# Titanium - how to edit contacts?

Tags: iphone, ios, titanium, contacts

how can I edit all users on Contacts ?

I know that with Objective C it can be done with an library adress something...

someone can tell me how can I edit all users on contacts list?

Thanks

Comment: What have your researched?

Comment: I look into Titanium's Doc in Ti.Contacts section but don't find anything saying how to EDIT an user... only create a new person

Comment: Check the answer and you will see how. Also please mark the answer correct if it helped you so it can help other when they come to the question looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any way within the documentation of Titanium to modify a person directly through defined methods you were correct about that.  However, if you look at the documention it provides everything you need to update a contact.  First you need to get a `person` object from one of the [following methods](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Contacts):

```
getPeopleWithName( String name ) : Titanium.Contacts.Person[]
getPersonByID( Number id ) : Titanium.Contacts.Person
```

Once you have the `person` object you need to use the methods listed [within the object](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Contacts.Person)

After you make changes to the `person` objects you wanted to make changes to you must use the save method [located here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Contacts).  What the function looks like:

```
save( Titanium.Contacts.Person[] contacts )
```

Also please make sure that you read the documentation well as it has a note at the top specifially for ios saying:

> iOS Platform Notes:
>   On iOS, the contacts database may be modified by an
>   external application, causing any Person or Group objects you've
>   retrieved to be out of sync with the database. The IDs of these
>   objects are not guaranteed to remain the same, so updating an object
>   when it is out of sync may have unpredictable results.
>
> To avoid this, listen for the reload event. When you receive a reload
>   event, you should assume that any existing Person or Group objects are
>   invalid and reload them from the Contacts module before modifying
>   them.
>
> See the examples for sample use of the reload event.

Comment: How can I use `reload` event to be able to get all ID's from my contacs?

e.g
I have 87 contacts on my list but when I tried to get them by ID only display contacts between 3-60

using `reload` event will avoid this to I be able to get all my contacts 1-87 ?

can you help me? and Thanks for reply @ObieMD5

Comment: got it!

I store unique ID by using `contact.recordId` -- iOS Only
for Android it can be done by `contact.id`

Thanks for your help @ObieMD5